# How to findOneAndDelete in mongodb using MongoRepository in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, crud

I am using a Spring web service and MongoDb to hold my data. Currently my Repository class extends MongoRepository and an obj of its interface gets injected into my Controller. 
There is no method for finding and deleting a specific entity in the MongoRepository interface. How can I do this without having to provide a concrete implementation? I need to do the operation at the same time.

Here's my code on github if its useful: https://github.com/RyanNewsom/DentistAppointmentSchedulerService

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this one out. I made a custom class and used MongoTemplate. You can then submit a query using mongoTemplate. It contains a lot more mongo specific implementation.

```
@Repository
public class AppointmentCustomRepository {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public Appointment getAppointmentAndDelete(String id) {
        return mongoTemplate.findAndRemove(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id)), Appointment.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample snippet to find and delete one document in Mongo DB using Java API's**

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("PasstheCollectionName");
Document document = collection.find.first();
Object value = document.get("_id");
Bson filter = Filter.and(Filter.eq("_id",value));
collection.findOneAndDelete(filter);
```